# QR code generate error

Tags: barcode, qr-code

i am trying to create QR code generation. I have installed tr_barcode module and qrtools.py.
It display barcode module in menu. Following errro comes while click generate Bar Image button.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140112_001021-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/tr_barcode/qrtools.py", line 116, in encode
    self.data_to_string()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

[image]

what did i mistake?

Comment: _“No such file or directory”_ – sounds like you did not set it up correctly, so that the script does not know the right directory to write the barcode image to.

Comment: ok how to set correct path? I just found and installed tr_barcode in openerp apps. then i copied qrtools.py pasted on addons folder. what will i do?

Comment: Check the readme file/documentation/whatever installation instructions they provide. And if that doesn’t help – contact their support.

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error in ubuntu 14 which was solved by installing qrencode ubuntu package. You can try

`apt-get install qrencode`

and try running the QR tool again